# No package g++ available. on HDP sandbox

Tags: software-installation, yum

I am trying to figure out how to install g++ on Hortonworks HDP

```
[root@sandbox-hdp Lesson-5.2_pipes]# uname -a
Linux sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com 4.19.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 27 12:40:57 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Anyway yum doesn't work

```
 yum install g++
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.uni-sofia.bg
 * epel: ftp.arnes.si
 * extras: centos.uni-sofia.bg
 * ius: lon.mirror.rackspace.com
 * updates: centos.uni-sofia.bg
No package g++ available.
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved

```
yum install gcc-c++
Installing:
 gcc-c++                                              x86_64                                      4.8.5-36.el7_6.2                                       updates                                      7.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
 libstdc++-devel                                      x86_64                                      4.8.5-36.el7_6.2                                       updates                                      1.5 M
Updating for dependencies:
 libstdc++                                            x86_64                                      4.8.5-36.el7_6.2                                       updates                                      305 k
```